# React - Page is not updating on the state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm first looping the data and displaying the state value. When we click on the entered text this should be reversed and displayed in the page. But, the state is getting updated. But, not updating in the page.

CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-framework-5odlcs?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
You can also mutate state using immerjs library below how it would look like with immer js
[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-paper-ro5pzr?file=/src/App.js:336-511)

```
    const h3ClickHandler = (index) => {
      setData(
      produce((draft) => {
        draft[index] = 
         draft[index].toString().split("").reverse().join("");
      })
    );
  };
```

======

Orignal Answer:
There is an issue with the h3ClickHandler you are mutating the state instead you should return a new instance of the array that is to do in an immutable way
You can modify the below h3ClickHandler method to below and give it a try:

```
const h3ClickHandler = (index) => {
    setData((prev) => {
      const dataVal = data[index].toString().split("").reverse().join("");
      const updateData = prev.map((p, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          return dataVal;
        }
        return p;
      });

      console.log(updateData);
      return updateData;
    });
  };
```

I have create the code sandbox example, which you can give it a try
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-lamarr-7ou2yg?file=/src/App.js:309-650

Comment: Bhavesh Daswani - Thanks for the solution. I tried and this solution is working.

Comment: For this simple problem we don't need `immer`

Answer (score 1):

React is smart enough to know when to re-render the component. If you are passing same array (same object reference) then It won't re-render. So you have to clone it or create a new array.

You can first create a clone of new array and then reverse the string.

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-mirzakhani-xiqg5i?file=/src/App.js)

```
  const h3ClickHandler = (index) => {
    setData((prev) => {
      const clone = [...prev];
      clone[index] = clone[index].split("").reverse().join("");
      return clone;
    });
  };
```

Or You can use map over to return new element and rever if the array index matched the clicked one as:

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-violet-4zw9tf?file=/src/App.js)

```
  const h3ClickHandler = (index) => {
    setData((prev) =>
      prev.map((str, i) =>
        i === index ? str.split("").reverse().join("") : str
      )
    );
  };
```

Comment: decpk - Thanks for posting the answer. This helped me a lot and I was able to find the solution.